# Angular UI - ui-select custom styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, jquery-ui

So I am using ui-select with angularjs to create a configurable directive. The functionality on the backend is almost done but our prototype has very specific styles and I need to adhere to those styles.

I would like to simply re-style the ui-select as I see fit but I can't seem to find a single tutorial online on how to do so. I have found a few examples on overriding the template that angular ui uses using $templateCache. Is there a way to simply have a css file somewhere that it uses instead of its default? Or is there a way to override the current classes without a bunch of !important tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can change the entire style of the UI-select directive by our own CSS. There is no restriction for that, take a look at sample CSS changes in the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv9mo66a/415/).

```
.ui-select-container {
  width:  200px;
}
.ui-select-bootstrap .ui-select-choices-row.active>a {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.ui-select-container input {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```